# Azure Function calling WIX Function with 429 Error

Tags: azure-functions, velo

Please can somebody advice where I am going wrong here.

I am running an Azure Function (c# .NET7). In this function, I call a WIX Backend HTTP Function which basically retrieves a JSON dataset from one of the WIX Collections, parses it in the C# code and Updates an AZURE SQL Database with the contents of the JSON data.

When I run this code locally on my dev machine it works 100%.

When I deploy the function to Azure and run the function I get an (Response status code does not indicate success: 429 (Too Many Requests).) Error. At first I thought maybe the WIX is limiting the calls, but when I call the WIX function in Postman I can call it repeatedly with no errors. But as soon as I try to make 1 call using the Azure function it bombs out.

Note, running the code locally on my machine multiple times works 100% as well.

I suspect there must be something in the way the Azure function is calling the WIX Function that is different to the way my machine or postman is calling the function.

Here is the code I am running:

```
try{
    HttpClient client = new();
    string url="https://theWIXbackendfunction......";

    string data = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
//THIS IS WHERE IS BOMBS
}
```

Any ideas?